# How can I install vue2leaflet in quasar?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, quasar, vue2leaflet

I am trying to install vue2leaftlet in my quasar version 2 vue version 3 project and it seems I can install it. I have followed this example https://techformist.com/using-vue-plugins-quasar/
but it won't work since I keep getting the following error:

```
vplugins.js?bfd0:5 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: vue2_leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.install is not a function
at eval (vplugins.js?bfd0:5)
at Module../src/boot/vplugins.js (app.js:85)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:217)
at Function.fn (app.js:482)
at async Promise.all (:8080/index 0)
```

Comment: What is vue2leaflet. A google search returns no results.

Comment: my bad , I meant vueleaflet